# semicircle progress bar with 3 values with different size and structure in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Semicircle Pie Chart with dynamic values with different size in angular js, whether this is achieved by div or any library available .

I need to acheive like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) by this [options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html?h=circumference) for semicircle pie chart.
Set javascript chart code inside a $timeout for use in Angularjs without problem.